# Little's MCAR Test in R BaylorEdPsych package does not work

Tags: r, dataset, package, missing-data

Okay so here's the deal. I have to use the BaylorEdPsych package in R to test whether the dataset that I have is MCAR or not.

I ran the LittleMCAR function in it with the sample dataset (EndersTable1_1) and it worked flawlessly.

When I try to run the dataset that I have into the function I get this error:

```
Error in eigen(sampmat, symmetric = TRUE) : 
    infinite or missing values in 'x'
```

I don't understand why this would throw an error when my dataset conforms to the structure of the sample data.

My dataset by the way is a time series that details climate variables for the year 2000 with daily resolution. 
Here's my dataset for anyone who wants to reproduce this problem. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8hGFkkZ5DlfZFl4MGxXY1Y2dlE

My code is below:

```
install.packages("BaylorEdPsych")
install.packages("mvnmle")

library(BaylorEdPsych)
library(mvnmle)

#<update>
data(EndersTable1_1) #retrieve the enders dataset
view(EndersTable1_1) #view the dataset on R's data viewer
LittleMCAR(EndersTable1_1)
#</update>

LittleMCAR(year_2000) #this is what I named the imported dataset
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks to anyone who replies.

Comment: The error message says you have "infinite or missing values" and looking at that file with a text editor shows you do have missing values. So we are wondering:  where is the problem with your reading of error messages?

Comment: Its supposed to have missing values. Even the sample dataset has some. Otherwise how would the function compute for MCAR missingness? Oh yeah, I remember you. Thanks for last time by the way. Helped quite a lot.

Comment: I wouldn't expect datasets with large blocks of rows with all NAs to have any reasonable filling in by a missing data application. I think that violates the assumptions of MCAR.

Comment: The other issue is that you have a column entirely of NA, something prohibited by the function `mlest` which is part of the `traceback()` result after your error message.

Answer (score 1):

After taking out the blocks of rows that were all NA and the column that was all NA, this succeeds:

```
LittleMCAR(year_2000[ !apply(year_2000, 1, function(x) all(is.na(x))), -10])
```

Comment: It violates the assumption of MCAR? So does that pretty much mean that the data may be MAR instead? I can get behind deleting the column with all NAs, since its consistent with other weather stations that I have as part of the total dataset. Its probably just a throw-in variable that the weather stations do not have any equipment for.

Comment: To my understanding of imputation the would be no basis for imputing a row with all NA, and similarly with a column of all NA. You need some sort of value to set a location in an embedded subspace from which you can then do some sort of "fuzzy prediction". This really is not the proper venue for arguing about what the LittleMCAR function _should_ do but doesn't. Either go to stats.stackexchange.com and argue with the statisticians or contact the package authors. I corrected your code. That's what SO is for.

Comment: Wasn't my intention to argue. I was just afraid that the data may be MNAR. Because MNAR's are a pain in the butt to deal with. Also there are no software implementations that I know of that do pattern-mixture models or selection models for that matter. I'm tempted to just mice it.